# Are class methods the best way in Objective-C to implement a factory method?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

It seems like I see a lot of class methods in Objective C that are like `+(NSString*)stringWithString:(NSString *)string` or `+(NSArray)arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)array`, etc. I am just starting to consider design patterns and to me these methods look like little factories that produce specific implementations of strings or arrays based on the paramaters provided (stringWith *string* , string *ByAppendingString*). In essence this looks a lot like the factory method with parameters demonstrated in the book *Design Patterns*. Is there a better way to do this? Should I be creating interfaces that mix these class methods and instance methods, or create Factory only objects that do not have any instance methods? I am confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While [Apple claims](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCreation.html) that these methods are factory methods, I argue that they're not the same as the Factory Method pattern in *Design Patterns*. The *DP* Factory Method pattern uses an abstract `Creator` class, with concrete subclasses that generate concrete `Product` classes. The methods you're describing (which are often called "convenience constructors") are almost never implemented that way. Apple's definition of a factory method is "a class method that, as a convenience to clients, creates an instance of a class. A factory method combines allocation and initialization in one step and returns an autoreleased instance of the class." That's why I believe the term "convenience constructor" is more appropriate and less confusing that "factory method."

`NSString` is a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ClassCluster.html), which has some passing similarities to the Factory Method pattern, in that you can receive different concrete classes from the same method call. But class clusters are different than Factory Method in that the superclass knows about all the subclasses, and it is the superclass that callers interact with. In the Factory Method pattern, callers interact with subclasses of the Creator class.

So to your question: you should create convenience methods when it is convenient to the caller. It supplements:

```
Foo *foo = [[[Foo alloc] initWithSomething:something] autorelease];
```

with

```
Foo *foo = [Foo fooWithSomething:something];
```

My experience building these is that 90% of the time you shouldn't. It's not worth the extra code. You should wait until you see that `initWithSomething:` is being called a *lot* with an `autorelease` right after it, and then you add a convenience constructor to make things more convenient. Things like `stringWith...` are in this class. They're called a lot.

Comment: I think this is where my confusion was coming from, Apple. I must have read that page at some point where they called them factory methods. They're really just shorthand for autoreleased objects then. That makes sense... so if I wanted to implemented the actual *DP* factory method pattern I would need to go ahead and create a regular old interface that I promised myself not to implement... there's no abstract designation in Obj-C...?

Comment: The near-equivalent of an abstract interface is a @protocol. There's no way to create a semi-abstract class, however, like you can in C++ that is enforced by the compiler. When I do this, I generally just call `NSAssert` in the abstract method to note that it's abstract.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a factory method has to be a class method, because you need the class to generate a new instance.  Apple's frameworks use a mix of factory methods (arrayWithObjects, for example), and non-factory initialization (initWithObjects).

Other than that, I'm not really sure I understand your question.  For most non-trivial classes, you'll have both class factory methods and instance initialization methods.

Comment: He's being confused by Design Patterns, a concept which is single-handedly responsible for more bad code than any other I've seen.

Comment: @DanielRHicks You're saying the Factory Method pattern is responsible for a lot of bad code? I very seldom see the actual Factory Method pattern in the wild. Do you mean the Abstract Factory pattern? I have seen that one badly used at times. Or do you mean some other factory pattern that isn't really a *DP* pattern? Or do you mean the concept of "patterns" is responsible for bad code?

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with using factory methods.  It's the "analysis" techniques in Design Patterns and related schemes (and their mechanical mapping to "patterns") that lead to illogically structured applications with lots of unnecessary modules and interfaces, and a lack of the right, "clean" interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

These methods are usually described by the documentation as convenience methods - Writing `[NSString stringWithString:s]` is just shorter then writing `[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:s] autorelease]`, but they do the same thing.

Regarding the factory angle, I feel that whether or not you treat these methods as a sort of factory is a matter of taste and depends on what your exact definition of a factory is.

Answer (score 0):

Class in Objective-C are also objects (Class Objects), the factory class design pattern is part of the language.